# Why this implementations have different results?

Tags: javascript, c#, hash, bit-manipulation

Hi i need to generate some hash / checksum from same text in `c#` and `ts/js`
i found some solution here on stackoverflow but have some issue

so my js

```
private getStableHash(s, hashlength) {
let hash = 0;
const bytes = this.string2Bin(s); 
for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    hash += bytes[i];
    hash += (hash << 10);
    hash ^= (hash >> 6);
}
// final avalanche
hash += (hash << 3);
console.log(hash);
hash ^= (hash >> 11);
console.log(hash);
hash += (hash << 10);
console.log(hash);
return Math.round(hash % hashlength);
}

 private string2Bin(str) {
 const result = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  result.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
 }
 return result;
 }
```

and c#

```
 private int GetStableHash(string s, int hashlength)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            hash += b;
            hash += (hash << 10);
            hash ^= (hash >> 6);
        }
        // final avalanche
        hash += (hash << 3);
        hash ^= (hash >> 11);
        hash += (hash << 10);

        return (int)(hash % hashlength);
    }
```

`getStableHash('dbo.files.xxx.yyy.zzz/aaa/3',10000000)`
returns 7414302 in both cases so it is FINE

but if i change this last line

```
  hash += (hash << 10);
```

to

```
  hash += (hash << 15);
```

in both implementations

`c#`change in this line 474798750 to -1986274658 and returns -6274658

and

`js` changein this line 474798750 to 2308692638 and returns 8692638

why is that ? what im missing here?
regards !

Comment: Because of `int hash` will make the number overflow. Change it to `long hash`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` in C# is a *singed 32bit integer*. If you do bitshifting that sets the first bit to 1, the number will get negative.

`number`s in JS are 64bit floating point numbers, with 52bit integer precision. Bitwise operators are however only done on a *32bit signed representation of the number*.

Therefore the bitshifting `<<` is the same in both, *but the addition* `+=` only works on 32 bit in C#, but on 52bit in JS.

Comment: so i should maybe do uint in c# ? but js does not have this type ? problem will be the same?

Comment: @d00lar forget my previous answer, that was totally wrong (js 32 bit representation is signed too). To get the same behaviour, you would have to use a representation in C# with more bits (e.g. `long` ... ?) then cast to 32 bits `int` before doing bitwise shifting

Comment: so make this hash variable long and hash += ((int)hash << 10);? but if the vaue in this long will be > int maxvalue then it will overflow ?

Comment: @d00lar, jup, just as in js.